# Splitting up text into separate rows - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop over a few hundred pages of a site and grab Buddhist quotes and then save them into a dataframe. I've mostly got the code working, but am struggling with parsing some of the text appropriately. On each page i'm scraping there are 5 quotes, and from what I can tell in the HTML output no obvious identifier for each. So i've attempted to loop over what I scrape from each page but it's either overwriting all previous quotes (i.e quotes 1-4) or just grouping them all together into a single cell.

See set-up and code below:

```
# For data handling:
import pandas as pd

# Set Pandas output options
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# For the scrape:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BShtml
import urllib.request as ur

# Make empty dataframe
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"quote":[], "quote_date":[], "page_no":[]})

# Populate dataframe with quotes for first three pages
for i in range(1, 4):
    url = "https://www.sgi-usa.org/tag/to-my-friends/page/" + str(i)
    r = ur.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BShtml(r, "html.parser")
    new_result = pd.DataFrame({
        "quote":[soup.find_all("div", class_="post-content")],
        "quote_date":[soup.find_all("div", class_="post-date")],
        "page_no": [str(i)]
    })
    emptydata = emptydata.append(new_result)
emptydata
```

As you can see from the image attached this is bundling each 5 quotes into a single cell and making a new row of the data for each page. Any thoughts on how I can split these up so I have one row per quote and date? I tried looping over `soup.find_all("div", class_="post-content")` but figure I must have been constructing the dataframe incorrectly as that overwrote all but the last quote on each page.

[what my dataframe currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQQPs.png)

Thanks in advance! Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to fix?

You should add an additional for loop to get your goal:

```
for post in soup.find_all("div", class_="quote-inner"):
    new_result = pd.DataFrame({
                "quote":[post.find("div", class_="post-content").get_text(strip=True)],
                "quote_date":[post.find_all("div", class_="post-date")[1].get_text()],
                "page_no": [str(i)]
            })
```

**Example**

```
# For data handling:
import pandas as pd

# Set Pandas output options
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# For the scrape:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BShtml
import urllib.request as ur

# Make empty dataframe
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"quote":[], "quote_date":[], "page_no":[]})

# Populate dataframe with quotes for first three pages
for i in range(1, 4):
    url = "https://www.sgi-usa.org/tag/to-my-friends/page/" + str(i)
    r = ur.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BShtml(r, "html.parser")
    for post in soup.find_all("div", class_="quote-inner"):
        new_result = pd.DataFrame({
            "quote":[post.find("div", class_="post-content").get_text(strip=True)],
            "quote_date":[post.find_all("div", class_="post-date")[1].get_text()],
            "page_no": [str(i)]
        })
        emptydata = emptydata.append(new_result)
emptydata
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. This has solved my problem

Comment: Can I ask what the `[1]` does on the `"quote_date"` line of the inner loop? The code works fine but would appreciate this clarification if you can help @HedgeHog

Comment: Cause there are two results in `find_all()` that matches the class `post-date` `[<div class="post-date">Daisaku Ikeda</div>, <div class="post-date">February 10th 2021</div>]`  and only the second represents the date. With `[1]` we select this list item directly

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!